# Laravel - belongsToMany efficient tag count?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Given the following belongsToMany relationship:

Tag Model:

```
class Tag extends Model
{
    public function posts (){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Post');
    }
}
```

Post Model:

```
class Post extends Model
{
    public function tags (){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag');
    }
}
```

What would be the most efficient and scalable way in laravel to query for the count of each tag, and order based on tag count from lowest to highest?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to get tags and their count you need to join **tags** table in order to fetch **Tag** data with **post_tag** table to get the number of times given tag was used to tag a post. You can do that with the following code:

```
// get Tag data and join with post_tag
$counts = Tag::join('post_tag', 'tags.id', '=', 'post_tag.tag_id')
// group by tags.id in order to count number of rows in join and to get each tag only once
->groupBy('tags.id')
// get only columns from tags table along with aggregate COUNT column    
->select(['tags.*', DB::raw('COUNT(*) as cnt')])
// order by count in descending order
->orderBy('cnt', 'desc')
->get();
```

This will give you a collection of **Tag** objects. You will find the count in their **cnt** attribute.

Comment: Hi jedrzej, thank you for your answer. It works but I am wondering if it's scalable at large number of posts/tags, or if there is a more efficient/scalable/speedier way to get the same output.

Comment: You can't do this kind of real-time calculation without a join. Alternative would be to store counts in Tag model - this way you could avoid joins and the query would be much more efficient, but you'd need to update the count every time a post is added with given tag.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [withCount](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models) method

> If you want to count the number of results from a relationship without
>   actually loading them you may use the withCount method

```
$posts = App\Post::withCount('tags')->get();

foreach ($posts as $post) {
    echo $post->tags_count;
}
```